# WSO2 not compatible with Docker

Tags: docker, wso2, swagger-ui

I had to shutdown wso2server to test an other API management tool on the same machine. The other tool provided a quick setup running on Docker so I had to install docker.

Now, when I shutdown every docker services and start wso2server again, it looks like some services detect docker virtual interface IP (172.17.0.1) instead of using the real IP (10.22.106.101) :

```
[2016-11-04 16:33:21,452]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://172.17.0.1:9443/carbon/
[2016-11-04 16:33:21,452]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Publisher Default Context : https://172.17.0.1:9443/publisher
[2016-11-04 16:33:21,452]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent API Store Default Context : https://172.17.0.1:9443/store
```

Log from a previous day with expected IP:

```
[2016-09-15 15:38:24,534]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  :
 https://10.22.106.101:9443/carbon/ {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
[2016-09-15 15:38:24,534]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  API Publisher Defa
ult Context : https://10.22.106.101:9443/publisher {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
[2016-09-15 15:38:24,534]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  API Store Default
Context : https://10.22.106.101:9443/store {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
```

This doesnt prevent WSO2 to start, but it prevents Swagger-UI to work because it's trying to reach services on 172.17.0.1 ending in timeout since this IP doesn't correspond to anything.

What can I do in order to have the real IP is detected again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set required IP in `carbon.xml`

```
<!--
   Host name or IP address of the machine hosting this server
   e.g. www.wso2.org, 192.168.1.10
   This is will become part of the End Point Reference of the
   services deployed on this server instance.
-->
<!--HostName>www.wso2.org</HostName-->

<!--
Host name to be used for the Carbon management console
-->
<!--MgtHostName>mgt.wso2.org</MgtHostName-->
```

And you may have to replace `${carbon.local.ip}` in api-manager.xml by required IP too.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer it put me on the good rails, but your "you may" is not really satisfying, it's like you are not sure what you are talking about. For detailed informations about this ${carbon.local.ip} auto-setting : http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2014-March/028681.html. So it's not "you may", when the IP detected is not the one you expected you HAVE to replace manually all ${carbon.local.ip} occurences.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to above we also need to edit the `/wso2am-2.0.0/repository/conf/api-manager.xml` file and change url value of `<GatewayEndpoint>` replace `${carbon.local.ip}`

Comment: It is not an addition to above. Above comment says : "you HAVE to replace manually all ${carbon.local.ip} occurences". Moreover, you are supposed to use "add a comment" not create a new answer to say this.