# WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 : white screens after installing https certificate

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've just installed a new https certificate in wso2carbon.jks corresponding to the DNS name of the machine, and I've removed the old certificate. I have also changed all occurences of "{carbon.local.ip}" and "localhost" in carbon.xml and api-manager.xml to replace them with the new name of the machine (which is mapped in /etc/hosts too) as I was told to here : [WSO2 not compatible with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426915/wso2-not-compatible-with-docker)

After this, it starts with no error or warning in wso2carbon.log,and I can connect to store or publisher and navigate a bit with no error. I can see a green icon in the URL bar indicating the certificate is well installed and corresponds to the address.

BUT, when I try to open any "application" : https://myname.domain.fr:9443/store/site/pages/application.jag?name=DefaultApplication, I get a HTTP 200 response with no content.

What can I do for this, what am I missing ? How can I get a log telling me what is happening (none of the existing log or web console show me anything) ?

Comment: Does this happen only at `application.jag`?

Comment: Yes mostly. It would be useful to know what service is called by application.jag with which URL. I'm planning a full reinstall with more limited replacements in config to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that this white screen problem can  be caused by H2 database corruption (even if in this case I had no message related to this). I plan to set up a MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use any reverse proxy web server like NGINX as frond-end for  WSO2. 
What will move ssl questions away from complicated JAVA based WSO2 to classic Nginx.