# WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 : white screen on the application view screen when running as a systemd service

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, systemd

Consecutively to [WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 : white screens after installing https certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638809/wso2-api-manager-2-0-0-white-screens-after-installing-https-certificate), I've just installed a fresh new WSO2 API Manager (single node) from the 2.0.0 zip distribution using MySQL Database to try to avoid problems related to H2 database.

After the install is complete, it starts with no warning and no error (after a few tries to get all things right in master-datasources.xml).

In publisher, I can log in as admin, create a new API, import swagger json contract, finalize API with no problem.

In store, I can log in as admin, view the API I've just created, create a new application via the right-side drop down menu, subscribe to it.

BUT when I try to open an application in order to generate keys and token, I just get a white empty screen. Nothing can help me in the logs :

```
[29/Nov/2016:16:17:33 +0100] "GET /store/site/pages/application.jag?name=MyNewApp&tenant=carbon.super HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "https://10.22.106.101:9443/store/site/pages/applications.jag?tenant=carbon.super" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
```

EDIT :
A few minutes after I get the page crash (maybe not related ?) I have this printing repeatedly in wso2carbon.log :

```
WARN {sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop} -  RMI TCP Accept-11111: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=11111] throws {sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

Again, this is a basic installation (unzip) plugged into MySQL database with no customization/configuration.

EDIT 2 : So I think I have found the cause, but not the solution. This problem does not occur when I launch via direct command line, it occurs only when I launch through systemd service :

```
sudo sytemctl start wso2am.service
```

/etc/systemd/system/wso2am.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=WSO2 API Manager

[Service]
User=linc

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c ". /etc/profile.d/setenv.sh; /home/linc/wso2am-2.0.0/bin/wso2server.sh start"
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So is WSO2 not compatible with systemd launching ? or am I missing some parameter ?

Comment: Nothing on wso2carbon.log? or in browser console?

Comment: Exactly. What can I do to make some logs appear somewhere ? What does this "application.jag" try to call ? Can I call it in an other way ?

Comment: To debug, you can put some logs in `repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/blocks/application/application-view/block.jag` and see where it fails. Put `new Log().info("This line is reached");` in few places, and see where it breaks.

Comment: Ok, I've put loggers everywhere in block.jag and now I can tell "grant_types = mod.getAllowedGrantTypes();" crashes the page silently. I can log something just before and nothing is logged after this statement. What should I do from now ?

Comment: `getAllowedGrantTypes()` is in `repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/modules/application/list.jag`. Please put some logs there too.

Comment: edit added in main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed [this blog post](http://legendans.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-write-systemd-service-to-start.html) to run APIM as a Linux service. Please have a look. It should work without a problem. (Make sure to add `#!bin/sh` at the top of `myService.sh`)

Comment: Ok thanks, it looks to run fine. I guess using "Type=forking" was not compatible with the way WSO2 works and some subprocess where killed.

Comment: You have to use "sudo" before each systemctl command and you have to use "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" after each modification applied to a .service file

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have WSO2 API manager running as a Systemd service.

This is my 'wso2apim.service' file

---

```
[Unit]
Description=WSO2 API Manager

[Service]
Environment= JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
WorkingDirectory=/opt/wso2/wso2am-2.0.0
User=wso2
ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/wso2/wso2am-2.0.0/bin/wso2server.sh
ExecStop= /bin/bash -c '/opt/wso2/wso2am-2.0.0/bin/wso2server.sh stop'
ExecReload=/bin/bash -c '/opt/wso2/wso2am-2.0.0/bin/wso2server.sh restart'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

It's simple, but tricky

1. The service type is simple (not fork or either). (Default value)
2. The ExecStart has not to include the 'start' option. With the
   start option, it tries a nohup, that is not working
3. But, the stop has to include the stop options

Hope it helps

Comment: Are you sure you don't need "RemainAfterExit=yes" ? Because the shell should exit right after  wso2server has launched his java subprocess, and then your service will be considered as terminated by systemd.